# Optimize serialization of a RoaringBitmap

Tags: java, bitmap

I am creating a bloom filter using [Roaring Bitmap](https://github.com/RoaringBitmap/RoaringBitmap)  [0.7.14](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.roaringbitmap/RoaringBitmap/0.7.14) . The integer values are in the range 0 to 838,860,800. There are 70,429,378 unique integers in the map. I want to serialize the bitmap with optimization. But the optimization is not getting kicked in. Are there any extra settings needed for optimization to get kicked in?

```
System.out.println(" getCardinality long "+ 
this.bitmap.getLongCardinality());// 70429378

System.out.println(" getSizeInBytes "+ 
this.bitmap.getSizeInBytes());// 104883208

System.out.println(" runOptimize was done? " + 
this.bitmap.runOptimize());// false

this.bitmap.serialize(out);

System.out.println(" serializedSizeInBytes "+ 
this.bitmap.serializedSizeInBytes());// 104960008
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using about 11 bits per integer value, which is a lot better than what you would do with a `Set<Int>` or even an array of `int`s.

What makes you think that your particular set should benefit from run compression? Does your data have many runs of consecutive values?

Comment: @sattu that would explain why run optimization does not provide any benefit.